# powershell download file from Get-PnPListItem

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Im new to scripting and powershell so bare with me.
My goal is to connect to Sharepoint online, and download the latest file uploaded to the a specific site.

Currently I am able to Connect to Sharepoint with Connect-PnPonline, then i use PnPListItem to query the file i need, but i am stuck at the last step to download the file.

here is my code:

```
cls
$SPOsite="https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/example"
$TargetFile="C:\example"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SPOsite -ClientId xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx -ClientSecret secretsecret112233
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List Documents | select -last 1 
$ctx= Get-PnPContext
foreach ($item in $ListItems)
{
        $file = $item.file
        $fileversions = $file.Versions
        $ctx.load($file)
        $ctx.load($fileversions)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-Host $file.Name,$fileversions.VersionLabel
}
Get-PnPFile -Url "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/example" -Filename $ListItems -Path $TargetFile -AsFile
```

Error message that i get is

```
Get-PnPFile : File Not Found.
At \\cifs-share.example.org\Usershome\user\Desktop\PowerShell\dwnldSPfiles.ps1:20 char:1
+ Get-PnPFile -Url "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/example" -Fi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPFile], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.GetFile
```

Comment: `I tried using Get-PnPfile but it failed.` How did it fail? Did you get an error message?

Comment: I tried with this line
Get-PnPFile -Url "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/example" -Filename $ListItems -Path $TargetFile -AsFile

but i get File Not Found, how do i pass the $ListItems return result to Get-PnPfile?

Comment: Please update your original post to include the error message.

Comment: updated the original post with error message, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$SharePointFolderPath = "Shared Documents"  
    $Files = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $SharePointFolderPath -ItemType File  
    foreach($File in $Files) {  
        if($File.Name -eq "file name"){
    Get-PnPFile -Url $File.ServerRelativeUrl -Path c:\Temp -FileName $File.Name -AsFile  
    }
        
    }
```

Url should be the ServerRelativeUrl to the file which you want to download.

Comment: that works, but ill have to specify which file to download in the code, my idea is to download the latest file which is written to the console from the line that reads "Write-Host $file.Name,$fileversions.VersionLabel"

Comment: i added your line "Get-PnPFile -Url $File.ServerRelativeUrl -Path c:\Temp -FileName $File.Name -AsFile" to the first loop i have and it works great! thank you

Comment: You are welcome.If my reply helps you, you could mark it as answer. Thank you.